# Alternatives to a Stop watch in a Released App

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I have a C# server app.

I receive jpegs from my client.

The jpeg is encoded with the time-stamp which I retrieve on Server Side.

I want to determine network latency.

So, as I cannot rely on the clocks on the PCs because they may be out of sync (even using UTCDateTime) I have to rely on what I know for sure.

What I know for sure is the time-stamp of the incoming jpeg and the time-stamp of the previous jpeg.

So, my idea was to use the stopwatch (system.diagnostics) object to count the miliseconds between frames and then calulate the latency from there.

However, I found this:

**Performance. Let's address the performance impact caused by instantiating a Stopwatch. The Stopwatch class is slower than many operations. This applies when you are using Stopwatch throughout the lifetime of your application for routine monitoring.
Result:
Using a Stopwatch is more expensive than simple operations in the .NET Framework.
And:
For this reason, Stopwatch itself can become a performance problem. We should not use it in production code in tight loops.**

so, that seems to rule this out for me because I am using a tight loop and the the number of jpegs coming could be as high as 20 per second (depending on strength of connections).

So, is there something else I can use for my scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a *specific* problem or are you asking in general? Where does the text in bold come from? The stopwatch class isn't slow, because it doesn't do *anything at all*. It stores a high performance counter value when you start it and compares it to the current counter value when you call Stop, Interval etc. As for the tight loop and jpegs - these things take *several* orders of magnitude more time than reading a counter

Comment: @Fabjan what does that have to do with performance measurements?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP said something about *simple operations* that he would like to use instead of `Stopwatch` to get latency... So if he's going to count timespan he'd need to execute his code in a separate thread isn't it  ?

Comment: @AndresSimpson the reason you should *not* use Stopwatch is that .NET *already* has a lot of network related performance counters. You don't need to write any special code to enable them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, thanks for your comment,  My specific problem is countering network latency. I experienced this yesterday when the internet was slow. So.. I have a jpeg that should have been displayed at say 10:00:00.001 and it came into my server at 10:00.05.001. So, it is now 5 seconds out of date so therefore I wish to skip sending this jpeg to my connected clients.  That embolded text came from here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Comment: @Fabjan 1) why use another thread to measure time 2) CancellationToken isn't related to that at all 3) starting a Task is *also* hundreds or thousands of time slower than reading a performance counter.

Comment: @closer please explain why off-topic. I am asking about using a stopwatch on my c# code and I am concerned about system.diagnostics stowatch performance over a long period of time. Seems like a coding question to me? :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson that link talks about tight loops - loops that run in nanoseconds and perform simple CPU operations like additions. In your case though, you perform operations that are a billion times slower.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks again for spending your time trying to help me.  My jpeg comes in and I perform some image enhancement on it and then I relay it via web sockets to my clients.  So, is this still 'light'? I very much value your experience/reply :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson that would be me and I just did. You don't describe a specific problem, just a faulty assumption based on different circumstances. A stopwatch does *not* affect a 5 sec wait, in fact it's almost  free to use. If you want to measure your application's performance though, use a profiler or collect the performance counters provided by .NET

Comment: @AndrewSimpson compared to a Stopwatch, this is a very heavy operation. 5 secs though is a very large delay. Without specifics though (as in actual code and timings), it's impossible to help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're correct about 3) but not about 1) 2) If let's say i'd like to implement my own stopwatch class or logics it has to count time in a separate thread otherwise it'd block the main thread where i run my code isn't it ? And about 2)  cancellation token is just one possible solution to use. If we count time in `while(condition)` rule. We can use it like : `while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)`. But you're right it takes a lot to instantiate a Task so it's not really effective.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for explaining. It IS appreciated. I will take 5 minutes to see if I can reword this question better and if I cannot I will delete it myself.Thanks for your honesty, time and help

Comment: @Fabjan you misunderstand how Stopwatch works. It *doesn't do anything*. It simply caches the current tick counter value when it starts. Nothing blocks *at all*. It doesn't count or increment anything itself. When you stop it, it reads the current value again and makes a comparison. By starting a different thread you introduce overhead that is significantly larger than the time span you want to measure. Finally, CancellationToken has nothing to do with timings, it's about *cancelling* only. What you wrote is no different than checking any other variable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and how do you believe Timer works ? In main thread ? *No*, it starts in a *separate* thread.

Comment: @Fabjan whilst some of your points deserver merits i also agree with Panagiotis that this will cause an unnecessary overhead but thanks for your input

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in regards to '5 seconds' is a large delay. I just used that figure as an example. It could be 1 second or 500 milliseconds. I just did not want to get into a discussion about WHY I needed so much control/measurement

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I am not proposing anything just expressed an idea that is not really good though... May be it's best here to use the standard .NET network related performance counters as they were specially designed for that.

Comment: @Fabjan It was good idea and very much appreciated. However, even if it was threaded out would not using a stopwatch so regularly still cause a performance hit?  I admit I am ignorant in all this

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/gfqgcc DateTime.UtcNow is faster than StopWatch but it's also less accurate, while StopWatch will measure the elapsed time, UtcNow will return 0. But I agree with the comments that you won't be creating a new StopWatch every 50 ms thousands of times so it shouldn't have a big impact.

Comment: @artm that is so cool. thanks

Comment: @artm the benchmark is meaningless. Not only are you comparing different things (reading time vs object allocations), you are using the *imprecise* UtcNow after a floating point division to measure elapsed time. The result is essentially random. In the first case, you read the current time. In the second, you don't - you allocate a new object even though you could call `ElapsedTicks` on the original stopwatch. The two snippets result in completely different values too. The first returns elapsed time since start. The second - nothing. Elapsed time is never measured